# TSQL Divide by Zero Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that is doing some math and in there are times where a number could be a zero that its dividing by which would cause an error.

I found something on this website about how to fix it but now the number doesnt change at all.

```
Example Data: 
los.shortTermLosses = 1
A.shortTerm = 15
Giving the equation of 1/15*12 = 0.8

COALESCE(los.shortTermLosses / NULLIF(A.shortTerm,0),0.00)* 12 AS shortTermAttrition
```

It has to be something I did to prevent the divide by zero error but not sure how to get it to work correctly. The current result is always the `0.00`

**Update**

For those who want to see the whole query..

```
SELECT A.QID,
          (SELECT    TOP 1 E.[FirstName],
                           E.[LastName],
                           E.[NTID],
                           E.[TitleDesc],
                           A.[countOfDirects],
                           A.[longTerm],
                           A.[shortTerm],
                           COALESCE(los.totalLosses,0) totalLosses,
                           COALESCE(los.longTermLosses, 0) longTermLosses,
                           COALESCE(los.shortTermLosses,0) shortTermLosses,
                           COALESCE(los.shortTermLosses / NULLIF(A.shortTerm,0),0.00)* 12 AS shortTermAttrition,
                           COALESCE(los.longTermLosses / NULLIF(A.longTerm,0),0.00)* 12 AS longTermAttrition,
                           COALESCE(los.totalLosses / NULLIF(A.countOfDirects,0),0.00)* 12 AS totalAttrition
            FROM     employeeTable_historical AS E
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT         COUNT(b.leaver) as [totalLosses],
                                        sum(case when b.term = 'LTA' then 1 else 0 end) as [longTermLosses],
                                        sum(case when b.term = 'STA' then 1 else 0 end) as [shortTermLosses]
                                FROM dbo.attritionData AS B
                                WHERE E.QID = B.supervisor
                                AND MONTH(B.leaveDate) = @month
                                AND YEAR(B.leaveDate) = @year
                                GROUP BY b.supervisor
            )los
            WHERE    E.qid = A.[QID]
                     AND CONVERT (DATE, dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1)) >= CONVERT (DATE, E.[Meta_LogDate])
            ORDER BY meta_logDate DESC
            FOR      XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS)
    FROM   (SELECT QID,
                   [timestamp],
                   [countOfDirects],
                   [longTerm],
                   [shortTerm]
            FROM   (SELECT QID,
                           [timestamp],
                           [countOfDirects],
                           [shortTerm],
                           [longTerm],
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QID ORDER BY [Timestamp]) AS Row
                    FROM   [red].[dbo].[attritionCounts]
                    WHERE  [mgrQID] = @director
                           AND YEAR(CAST ([timestamp] AS DATE)) = @year
                           AND MONTH(CAST ([timestamp] AS DATE)) = @month) AS Tmp1
            WHERE  Row = 1) AS A
    FOR    XML PATH ('DirectReport'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('Root');
```

Comment: I am using SQLServer 2008

Comment: Without any coding, just speaking of a requirements - what do you expect to get as equasion result if `shortTerm` is `NULL` ?

Comment: `0.00` is what I want for anything that has a null value or the divide by zero error. In this case, I do have valid numbers for the equation but it still shows the `0.00`

Comment: Is `shortTermLosses` an Integer ? Then change it to `COALESCE(los.shortTermLosses*1.0 / NULLIF(A.shortTerm,0),0.00)* 12 AS shortTermAttrition` >>`Select 1/@shortTerm = 0?`

Comment: Can we easily turn that into a normal percentage ? `0.799999999992%`

Comment: `select 
COALESCE(Cast(@shortTermLosses as Float) / NULLIF(@shortTerm,0),0.00)* 12 AS shortTermAttrition
`

Comment: Not quite correct - `8.000000000000000e-001%`

Comment: I would not use float, if you can avoid it.

Comment: Which is 0.8, you did not show the other datatypes, Decimal(X,Y), Float, Money ....

Comment: The data types for `shortTermLosses` and `shortTerm` are INT single value like shown in the example of `1` and `15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error does not come from the NULLIF, you are just dividing an Integer e.g. 1 / 15 = 0
, just change your term to:
`COALESCE(CAST(los.shortTermLosses as float) / NULLIF(A.shortTerm,0),0.00)* 12 AS shortTermAttrition`

The closest transformation for you XML export might be casting the Result as money

```
Declare  @shortTermLosses int = 1
Declare  @shortTerm int = 15

select 
CAST(
COALESCE(CAST(@shortTermLosses AS float) / Cast(NULLIF(@shortTerm,0) AS float),0.00)* 12 
as Money)
AS shortTermAttrition
FOR      XML PATH (''), TYPE, ELEMENTS
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused.. The output of the XML is as follows using your code `    <shortTerm>15</shortTerm>
    <totalLosses>2</totalLosses>
    <longTermLosses>1</longTermLosses>
    <shortTermLosses>1</shortTermLosses>
    <shortTermAttrition>8.000000000000000e-001</shortTermAttrition>`

Comment: You will have to find the appropriate type to cast for your data, may be money, float, decimal(x,y), it depends on the data types used for shortTerm.